# Does a VPN hide the Device's name in a Local Network?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, home-networking

Connecting to a **Local network**, you can often see the **Names** and MAC Adress of all connected devices. My question is if a VPN does hide your **local IP adress** , Device Name and MAC Adress, or if it just masks your public IP Adress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPN doesn't hide your local IP address nor your device name, or MAC address. As long as you are connected to a network, you will have a local IP address whether you're connected to a VPN or not. Whenever you're connected to a VPN, you still have to make requests to the router, which requires a local IP. A VPN encrypts the traffic that is routed through the VPN, it doesn't skip the router; VPN traffic is just encrypted, not "hidden." Only the contents of the packets, and where they are being routed to, are encrypted, not how many packets are sent, or anything else.

Essentially: A VPN hides your actual public IP address to any server that you're connecting to from the VPN. If you're connected to a network, and want to use it in any manner, you cannot avoid having a local IP address.

Comment: thank you for this answer!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a VPN can hide the device's name in a Local Network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).